# General question about showing equality in an inner product space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

so what I am trying to show is that $x = y$ in an inner product vector space (also happens that is Hilbert as well). What I have managed to show is that for all $\epsilon >0$, $||x - y|| < \epsilon$. My question is very simple is this enough for me to claim that $x = y$?

My understanding is that yes this is enough, because for each neighborhood around $x$, we have $y$ in there as well thus in terms of the norm/metric we cannot distinguish between the two, so they are the same.

On the other hand why I am careful and want a second opinion is I recall from topology that sometimes if we have a space without a metric, things can get weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it follows from the basic properties of real numbers that $||x-y||=0$. And the nondegeneracy of the inner product means that this implies $x-y=0$. In general this would work in any normed vector space, since it's always an assumption that only the zero vector has zero norm.